# Ajax.ActionLink insert after header in a table?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a `<table>` that has a header row. I'm trying to add an item under the header row, but there seems to be no way to describe this intent to the `ActionLink` function.

`InsertionMode.InsertBefore` with the header row's ID specified as the update target just puts the row on the top of the table, `Replace` replaces the header of the table, and `InsertAfter` actually puts a new row inside the header row -- which is obviously invalid.

Is there any way to specify that I want to *append* some HTML after or before a tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to achieve such behavior with only properties of the `AjaxOptions` class. One way would be to subscribe for the `OnSuccess` method and do the insertion manually:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("click me", "someAction", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success" })
```

and the `success` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function success(result) {
        $('table').after('th').append(result);
    }
</script>
```

or if you are using MicrosoftAjax you need to call the `get_data` method to fetch the returned result from the ajax call:

```
function success(result) {
    $('tableid').after('th').append(result.get_data());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery.

```
$("tableid").after("<th></th>").append("whatever");
```

Comment: Yeah of course I could do this in jquery using `$.ajax()`, but my question is how to do this using Ajax.ActionLink in MVC.